# Install Linux from ISO image to external HDD partition

Tags: linux-distribution

I'm using windows OS, and need to install some linux distribution to HDD partition. I already downloaded my linux distro as ISO image, but don't want to burn that to DVD disk (because there is no available in my village). So I need to install that directly to some partition in my external HDD. Or if this not possible, I need to install that to some USB flash drive, with single partition. Impossible for me to wipe out all data in my external HDD, so I create some partition in it.

Remember, not needed to burn that ISO image to DVD.

Comment: this has nothing to do with software recommendation and should be on [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se]

Comment: Did you try [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/tr/) for USB media?

Answer (score 1):

UNetbootin (short for “Universal Netboot Installer”) is software that allows you to easily create bootable USB flash drives to install or use operating systems. This software is designed to be cross-platform and works with Windows, as well as Mac and Linux operating systems.

just follow the instructions
https://unetbootin.github.io